# EEA Family Permit Refused for Mother-In-Law - next steps?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, eu-citizens, family, refusal

I have my grand mother who is around 80 and lives in India with my brother.

My mom is a Portuguese national and she sponsored my dad to come to UK as my dad holds Indian citizenship.

Advised by local agents, we applied for my grand mother as dependent member of EEA national as my mom sends money to her every month and visit her in once in a couple of years.

We applied for her 4 times and it got rejected every time with almost similar reasons like you are not financially dependent, etc.

Below is the refusal reason from her latest (fourth) attempt.

[image: Refusal letter grand mother]

We are not sure what to do now. Thinking to appeal this time but not sure if that will be a good choice given we have to pay huge fees to solicitors.

Please advise what next we should try?

**UPDATE :**

I was advised by one of our relative that I should try to sponsor my grand mother as I am also a Portuguese citizen living in UK. But I recently got visa for my wife on my sponsorship ( Spouse - EEA Family Member).

I am not sure if that will help, since we have been showing that my grand mother as dependent on my mother for her 4 applications and also as I have sponsored already my wife as dependent on me.

Any advice on that?

Comment: Have you tried submitting documents to prove/demonstrate the things they ask for? Looks to me like they've been quite helpful in telling you what they'll need to see

Comment: It is disheartening that the UK does not know the difference between "descendant" and "ascendant."

Comment: @Gagravarr what evidence can we provide for "wholly or mainly financially dependent"

Comment: The letter seems to imply that they want evidence of her total budget, so they can establish that the payments are a significant part of it, and that she would not be able to support herself without them.  Have you looked at the cited regulations?

Comment: Never mind, I looked at the regulations, and they provide no guidance for evaluating whether someone is a dependent.  You'll need to find the specific test that the officer is supposed to use for that so you can understand whether your grandmother qualifies, and, if so, how to demonstrate that.  I'm concerned about the implied requirement that the dependency be of necessity and not by choice; it seems to leave far too much room for subjective opinion.

Comment: @phoog I updated the question, please have a look when you get time, thanks.

Comment: Do you or your wife support your grandmother?

Comment: no we don't support yet, shall we?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara do you understand the significance of support in this application?

Comment: @phoog I do understand partially like sending money, and showing expenses, but the problem is in India, no one would give bills for daily stuff and the utility bills are on my dad's name who is in UK.

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara If you manufacture some appearance of support, they are likely to see through you.  The question is: who is *actually* supporting her.  That person must be the sponsor.  Do you understand why?  Asking whether it's better for you or your wife to sponsor her implies that you do not understand the reason for the rejection.  It's fine for the utility bills to be in your dad's name, as long as the (1) utility bills are for the place where your grandmother lives and (2) the sponsor is paying for the utility bills.  If your dad is paying them, maybe your dad should be the sponsor.

Comment: @phoog ok I got your point, and will think over it in detail and plan my next step, thank you very much.

Comment: Sad to inform, my grand mother passed away couple of months ago, it was one of her wish to visit UK which we could not make it for her :(. But hope someone will be helped with this question/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refusal letter shows that there was not enough evidences to calculate your grandmother's basic living costs, to determine her cost of living and how much is being contributed by the sponsor. When the case workers consider whether your grandmother is financially dependent, they consider the following:

From the [Direct Family Members Guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/464872/Direct_Family_Members_v3_0.pdf) document:

> Essential Needs:
>
> You must consider the following:
> does the applicant need financial support to meet their essential needs from the EEA national;
>
> If the applicant cannot meet their essential living needs without the financial support of the EEA national, they must be considered dependent even if they also receive financial support or income somewhere else
>
> Essential needs include accommodation, utilities and food. Dependency must be shown by financial documents that show money being sent by the sponsor to the applicant. If the applicant is receiving financial support from the EEA national as well as others, they must show that the support from the EEA national is supporting their essential needs.
>
> The applicant does not need to be dependent on the relevant EEA national to meet all or most of their essential needs. For example an applicant can still be considered dependent if they receive a pension to cover half of their essential needs and money from the relevant EEA national to cover the other half.

Finally, to respond on whether you should become the sponsor, it may be seen as convenience and also there will not be a history of financial dependency. The rule does not prevent you sponsoring your grandmother as long as you have the financial capability.

Comment: @ICSLegal I've edited your answer and used '>' to indicate a quote. I've also included a link to the source of the quote.